# Sendgrid and AWS Lambda Serverless Form

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sendgrid

I am trying to set up a super basic email form using Sendgrid and AWS Lambda.  I am having problems sending data from the form to the Lambda function.  The error I get is "Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0".  I know it is something to do with how I am sending the body.  Below is my code for my Lambda function.

```
require("dotenv").config();
const sendgrid = require('@sendgrid/mail');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
sendgrid.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
var data = JSON.parse(event.body);
const msg = {
    to: data.to,
    from: 'test@gmail.com',
    subject: data.subject,
    text: data.message,
};
sendgrid.send(msg);
callback(null, 'Message Sent');
}
```

Here is the Javascript for my form.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var to = $("#to").val();
    var subject = $("#subject").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();

    var data = {
        'to': to,
        'subject': subject,
        'message': message
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'https://xxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/xxxxx',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({data}),
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        success: function(res){
            console.log('Email was sent.');
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('Error.');
        }
    });

})

});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try putting quotes around your data in the "data" object:
data = { "to": "\"" + to + "\"", ......} and see if that helps.

Comment: Do your JSON.stringify outside of the ajax settings, so you can console.log the result and make sure you know what is being sent. If it looks like OK JSON (or simply doesn't throw an exception when stringifying) then your problem is on the lambda side. Check to make sure event.body is actually present, console.log it to check. That specific JSON parse error you're getting is usually a sign that you're trying to parse an undefined value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to parse a JSON object, not a string.

> var data = JSON.parse(event.body);

This is not correct. Just assign,

> var data = event.body;

It should take care from there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Lambda doesn't parse JSON bodies automatically, so this should not be the issue here. It is much more likely that `event.body` is actually undefined

Comment: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 . This error happens when you try to parse JSON object or even undefined. You try to print console.log(event.body) to checkout the values.